# How to move up items by group and update each position?

Tags: javascript, sorting, grouping

I'd like to move array items (by group) up and down. The items are sorted by position.

Here's the **current data**:

```
| Index | Name | Pos | Group | Level
------------------------------------
| 0     | A    | 11  | 1     | 1
| 1     | B    | 12  | 1     | 1
| 2     | C    | 21  | 3     | 2
| 3     | D    | 22  | 3     | 2
| 4     | E    | 23  | 3     | 2
| 5     | F    | 31  | 2     | 2
| 6     | G    | 32  | 2     | 2
```

- Index: the given index (auto)
- Pos: every item has a unique position, composed of two numbers: the first number counts up everytime when the group changes, the 2nd one counts up within the group.
- Group: items are sorted in groups
- Level: Groups can only be moved within the same level

I'd like to move every item of group 2 up, above group 3. The **result should be**:

```
| Index | Name | Pos | Group | Level 
------------------------------------
| 0     | A    | 11  | 1     | 1
| 1     | B    | 12  | 1     | 1
| 2     | F    | 21  | 2     | 2
| 3     | G    | 22  | 2     | 2
| 4     | C    | 31  | 3     | 2
| 5     | D    | 32  | 3     | 2
| 6     | E    | 33  | 3     | 2
```

I don't know how to do this the easy way. My try ended up in chaos. **Pseudocode**:

```
items = new Array(); // global array, filled with the data above

function move_up(group_id) {
    // get group
    var group = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if (items.group_id == group_id) 
            group.push(items[i]);
    }

    // get parent group
    var parent_group = new Array();
    var parent_group_id = 0;
    var level = group[0].level;
    var get_next = false;
    var x = 0;
    for (var i = items.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (items[i].group_id == group_id) {
            get_next = true;
        }

        if (get_next == true && 
            items[i].level == level && 
            items[i].group_id != group_id) {
            if (x == 0) {
                parent_group_id = items[i].group_id;
            }

            if (items[i].group_id == parent_group_id) {
                parent_group.push(items[i]);
            }

            x++;
        }
    }

    parent_group.reverse();

    // rebuild items array
    var items_new = new Array();
    var pos_1 = 1;
    var pos_2 = 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if (items[i].group_id == group_id) {
            // do nothing
        } else if (items[i].group_id == parent_group_id) {
            // add group before parent group
            for (var k = 0; k < group.length; k++) {
                group[k].pos = pos_1 + pos_2;
                items_new.push(group[k]);                  
            }

            // add parent group after group
            for (var k = 0; k < parent_group.length; k++) {
                parent_group[k].pos = pos_1 + pos_2;
                items_new.push(parent_group[k]);                  
            }               
        } else {
            items[i].pos = pos_1 + pos_2;
            items_new.push(items[i]);
        }
    }

    return items_new;
}
```

**2nd try:**

```
function move_up(group_id, parent_group_id) {
    items.sort(function(a, b) {
        // what here? move group up, parent_group down. what, if the groups 
        // have not the same num of items?


        // make sure, both items have the same level
        if (a.level == b.level) {
            // move group up
            if (a.group_id == group_id) {
                return -1;
            }

            // move parent group down
            if (a.group_id == parent_group_id) {
                return 1;
            }
        }        
    });
}
```

It's not working and looks stupid. I'd appreciate if anyone could give me an thinking-impulse!

**Problems**:

- How to avoid a chaos code like this? Do you know a better way?
- Where to count pos_1 and pos_2 up?

Comment: Why not use a sort function? or you need to be able to move specific groups?

Comment: @eric.itzhak: thanks for your fast reply. I don't want to sort, I'd like to modify the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort
You need to define a comparison function which uses Group Id.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I updated the Question with the example of my second try. Would be great, if you could check it and maybe give me an advice. Thanks!